# sql injection in Microsoft SQL Server 2017 problem retrieving db names

Tags: sql-injection, server, sqlmap

While I was pentesting, I came across a blind sql injection in a website that uses IIS. I tried this payload `" AND 11=11 AND ('Hlua'='Hlua"` and it works and it gives success page then i tried `" AND 11=12 AND ('Hlua'='Hlua"` and it gives error pages after that i open sqlmap and pass this command

```
sqlmap -u "https://example.com/popup.aspx?vote=4444" -p "vote" --random-agent --level=5 --risk=3 --dbms="Microsoft SQL Server" --threads=10 --no-cast --current-db -v3
```

and it confirmed the vulnerability.

But when tried to retrieve the current-db or users or banner it returned nothing. When I try `--is-dba` it returns false.

This is the payload I used [image]

`"') AND UNICODE(SUBSTRING((SELECT DB_NAME()),1,1))>32 AND ('dPwr'='dPwr"`

But it had an empty response.

There is no sign of a firewall even in sqlmap.

I tried to use `--common-tables --common-columns` and it fetches me tables and columns but I can't get database names.

any help?

Comment: Why would you expect to get data back from a blind SQL injection? If you can write to a field that the API will let you read back, can you exfiltrate data that way?

Comment: @le3th4x0rbot i cant use substring and isnull and many functions because of the permission but i can check existance of tables and columns using this query "EXISTS(SELECT username FROM dbo.users)" do you mean by write to field to check if i have the write permission

Comment: Ok, after some research sqlmap is using side channel magic to exfiltrate data, so that part makes sense. Restricting a webserver's user permission on the database to the minimum necessary is a relatively common security precaution. Usually this is at least siloed in a single database. Obviously the webapp developer is a goof, but that doesn't mean whoever hosts the database is.

Comment: @le3th4x0rbot any way or obfuscation technique to bypass or overide unusability of ASCII or SUBSTRING

Comment: Have you tried any of the other techniques? https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Techniques